# AurioTouch2 sound frequency

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, fft

Is there a way to get the frequency value in Apple's example project AurioTouch2? I've been looking all over for an answer to this and couldn't find one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps

1.
The try-it-out way

FFTs use frequency bins and the bin frequency width is based on the FFT parameters. To find a frequency you will need to record it sampled at a rate at least twice the highest frequency present in the sample. Then find the time between the cycles. If it is not a pure frequency this will of course be harder.

2.
I heard of the frequency of each bin is

```
yFract * hwSampleRate * 1/2
```

yFract is the half of fftLength and the last bin of the FFT corresponds with half of the sampling rate. Using it like this way

```
NSLog(@"The magnitude for %f Hz is %f.", (yFract * hwSampleRate * .5), (interpVal * 120));
```

Comment: You deserve the bounty. Thanks a lot